# how to model a state space with GARCH noise

Tags: garch, state-space-models

[image]

I'm trying to model a state space model with GARCH noise and get stuck by the complexity of the equation. 
so the first equation is a observation equation and second one is a state equation where both q(t) and $\gamma_q(t)$ follows AR(1), however, q(t) had a GARCH error term where I do not know how to model with. 
I have looked into python's statsmodel package and R's KFS, but did not find anything useful, please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should input the garch matrix into the likelihood as they do [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MARSS/vignettes/EMDerivation.pdf) for Expectation Maximization at pag 22. Take the likelihood expression, then you are not forced to actually use Expectation Maximization to maximize it. This general formulation helps a lot when it comes to writing the likelihood of a complex state space form model.